# Multiple mod rewrites in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, variables

I want the following rules but I don't seem to get the right setup.

`<domain>/training-courses/`

both with or without the slash at the end it should go to:

`<domain>/?index.php?page=training-courses`

and for each variable extra after this I want it to behave like this:

`<domain>/training-courses/success/another-value/and-yet-another/`

to

`<domain>/?index.php?page=training-courses&val1=success&val2=another-value&val3=and-yet-another-value`

If it's not possible to have the option for unlimited leading variables, i'd like to have at least 2 variables after the page variable

Is this possible? and how do I get this sorted out?

I have this so far:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^test/([^/]*)/$ /test/index.php?pagina=$1&val1=$2
RewriteRule ^test/([^/]*)$ /test/index.php?pagina=$1&val1=$2

RewriteRule ^test/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /test/index.php?pagina=$1&val1=$2
RewriteRule ^test/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /test/index.php?pagina=$1&val1=$2

RewriteRule ^test/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /test/index.php?pagina=$1&val1=$2&val2=$3
RewriteRule ^test/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /test/index.php?pagina=$1&val1=$2&val2=$3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to come back to my own question and answer it. For a while now i'm using exactly what I want.

First off I have this in my htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    # existing folders or files
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.* - [L]

    # non-existing folders or files
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/? index.php?p=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

This allows to access real files at all times. If the path does not exist it will pass the entire path to index.php.

In index.php I have the following code at the top:

```
// Split the URL in all its components
$request = parse_url(strip_tags($_GET['p']));
// Only take the path without any leading slashes
$path = rtrim($request['path'], '/');
// Split each variable from eachother
$path_array = explode("/", $path);

if(count($path_array)){
    // By default I select the first variable as the page I will include later on
    $page = $path_array[0];

    // Each other variable I will pass as $val[#nr] starting with 1. Just to be sure I'm going to strip tags and slashes
    for($i=1;$i<count($path_array);$i++){
        $path_array[$i] = strip_tags($path_array[$i]);
        $path_array[$i] = stripslashes($path_array[$i]);
        $val[$i] = $path_array[$i];
    }
}
else{
    // If $path_array doesn't contain multiple variables lets assume $path will contain the $page
    $page = $path; 
}

// If $page is empty let's take on the default page to include later on
if(empty($page)){
    $page = "home";
}

if(file_exists($page . ".php")){
    include($page . ".php");
}
else{
    echo "Page " . $page . ".php does not exist.";
}
```

To give you some examples of the posibilities:

domain.com/ will include home.php
domain.com/product/ will include product.php
domain.com/product/298833/ will include product.php and parse 298833 as $val[1];
domain.com/product/298833/purple-candle will include product.php and parse 298833 as $val[1]; and purple-candle as $val[2]; Notice the leading slash not being included. It does not matter.

I'm open for improvement or tips in general. For now this is definitely the answer I was looking for back when I asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

You're quite correct, you can't handle unlimited variables as sub-folders in the way you would like to, mod_rewrite just doesn't support it.

However, in answer to your first problem, to make the trailing / optional, change your rules to the following:

```
RewriteRule ^test/([^/]*)/?$ /test/index.php?pagina=$1

RewriteRule ^test/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /test/index.php?pagina=$1&val1=$2

RewriteRule ^test/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /test/index.php?pagina=$1&val1=$2&val2=$3
```

Comment: When I do exactly that I get an "Internal Server Error", but thanks for the tip regarding the trailing slash

Comment: Ah sorry, I probably should've done a quick test before posting that.

Answer (score 0):

After hours and hours of struggeling it just WON'T work. Since unlimited variables just isn't supported I'm ok with two variables besides the page (pagina). What I have now is this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(test/images|test/css|test/js|test/lib)($|/) - [L]

RewriteRule ^test/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ test/index.php?pagina=$1&e=$2&t=$3
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) test/index.php?pagina=$1&e=$2&t=$3
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)/(.*)/ test/index.php?pagina=$1&e=$2
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)/(.*) test/index.php?pagina=$1&e=$2
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)/ test/index.php?pagina=$1
RewriteRule ^test/(.*) test/index.php?pagina=$1
```

**None** of the RewriteRules work except from the first one which excludes folders from the other rewriterules. With working I mean it will actually redirect the URLs to index.php but I can't get the values in PHP through ie $_GET['pagina']

Strange thing is this WILL work, though is way too limited for my liking:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(test/images|test/css|test/js|test/lib)($|/) - [L]

RewriteRule ^test/(.*)/ test/index.php?pagina=$1
```